# Best way to store data and have ordered list at the same time

Tags: redis, cron, sortedset

I have those datas that change enough not to be in my postgres tables.
I would like to get tops out of those data.
I'm trying to figure out a way to do this considering :

- Easiness of use
- Performance

**1. Using Hash + CRON to build ordered sets frequently**

In this case, I have lot of users data stored in hash like this :

`u:25463:d = { "xp":45124, "lvl": 12, "like": 15; "liked": 2 }`

`u:2143:d = { "xp":4523, "lvl": 10, "like": 12; "liked": 5 }`

If I want to get the top 15 of the higher lvl people. I dont think I can do this with a single command. I think I'll need to SCAN the all u:x:d datas and build sorted sets out of it. Am I mistaken ?
What about performance in this case ?

**2.Multiple Ordered sets**

In this case, I duplicate datas.
I still have to first case but I also update datas in the differents sorted sets and I don't need to use a CRON to built them.

I feel like the best approach is the first one but what if I have 1000000 users ?

Or is there another way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility would be to use a single sorted set + hashes.

The sorted set would just be used as a lookup, it would store the key of a user's hash as the value and their level as the score.

Any time you add a new player / update their level, you would both set the hash, and insert the item into the sorted set. You could do this in a transaction based pipeline, or a lua script to be sure they both run at the same time, keeping your data consistent.

Getting the top players would mean grabbing the top entries in the sorted set, and then using the keys from that set, to go lookup the full data on those players with the hashes.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I love this idea, it's great thanks ! One more question though : Do you think I should store lvl in the hash even if the value is also in the sorted set ? I could avoid duplication. This means that when I need the data of a particular id, I have to get the hash and also look for the lvl in the sortes set. What about performance in the case ?

Comment: That's a really clever idea to remove the duplication.
You could use ZSCORE to lookup the level directly in the sorted set, which being an O(1) operation should be very fast and have almost no impact on performance. Just be sure to pipeline both reads so you're not paying any extra overhead on running two commands.

Comment: In general it's great to look at the O() notation listed for each command. http://redis.io/commands/zscore

Anything with 0(1) is pretty much free. It means that no matter how much data you have it takes the same amount of time.

O(n) means that if you have n number of data points, it would take n number of steps in the algorithm. Think of n like a variable in algebra. 

In general keeping to o(1) and o(lg n) are what you want to keep things cost effective for games that hope to scale. 

For reference check this: his out https://rob-bell.net/2009/06/a-beginners-guide-to-big-o-notation/

Comment: Great. I never understood the O() notation. Now I do, thanks to you. I'm gonna look at what I've already done, to see if I'm not using method that use to many time. You helped me a lot here. Thanks, really.